# How to change a hidden value based on the class it has

Tags: jquery, html

I have some markup:

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="deleted" value="False" />
                <input type="button" class="rtButton" value="RT" />
            </td>                               
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="deleted" value="False" />
                <input type="button" class="rtButton" value="RT" />
            </td>                               
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="deleted" value="False" />
                <input type="button" class="rtButton" value="RT" />
            </td>                               
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I'm wanting to happen is when an rtButton is clicked the value of just the hidden input within the same td is changed to true.

I tried to achieve this with:

```
$(function(){

    $('.rtButton').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('input.deleted').val("True");
        alert( $(this).closest('input.deleted').val())
            });


});
```

However it can't seem to set the value.

Comment: You probably should be applying name to all your input fields (that is if you ever actually want to post the data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `siblings()` method:

Adding demo anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/qZBkt/3/

```
$(function(){
    $('.rtButton').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('input.deleted').val("True");
    });
});
```

[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: according to that definition of closest it should have worked.

Comment: @AnonyMouse no, closest selects the closest parent.

Comment: +1 indeed for this. And I have added the demo hope you cool with it :P

Answer (score 1):

or like this: **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qZBkt/

Hope this feed your cause! `:)`

**code**

```
$(function() {

    $('.rtButton').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.deleted').val("True");
        alert($(this).parent().find('.deleted').val());
    });


});​
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches ancestors elements for a match, use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select the input

```
$(function(){

    $('.rtButton').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('input.deleted').val("True");
        alert( $(this).siblings('input.deleted').val())
            });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naaeM/1/